# NextJS doesn't set cookie from backend (nextjs, echo golang)

Tags: javascript, go, next.js, cookies, echo

nexjs frontend:

```
    async function getData() {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
            credentials: 'include'
        })
    
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch')
        }
        return res.json()
    }
    
    export default async function Page() {
        const data = await getData()
    
        return <div>{data.message}</div>
    }
```

echo golang backend:

```
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
            AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
            AllowHeaders: []string{"*"},
            AllowCredentials: true,
        }))
    
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        cookie := new(http.Cookie)
        cookie.Name = "name"
        cookie.Value = "value"
        cookie.MaxAge = int(time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 7).Unix())
        cookie.Path = "/"
        c.SetCookie(cookie)
    
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, echo.Map{"message": "Hello, World!"})})
```

package.json:

```
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
```

It works fine in Postman, React, Svelte, but not in NextJS (no errors in browser console and in terminal)

[devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4grZb.png)

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6VYr.png)

[svelte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzVUO.png)

upd: I need something like this for app router

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    setCookie('test', 'value', { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 6 * 24 });
    getCookie('test', { req, res});
    getCookies({ req, res});

    ...
}
```

Comment: MaxAge is not a timestamp.

Comment: @Volker thanks, but problem still exist

Comment: Inspect the Console tab. Do you get a CORS error? I'm guessing you do, and it likely tells you that you cannot use `*` in conjunction with credentialed requests; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards. You'll have to list the exact origin(s) (e.g. `https://youclient.com`) you wish to allow in your CORS configuration.

Comment: @jub0bs console is clear, ```AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"}``` doesn't solve

Comment: @dopesoul What version of Echo are you using? And @Volker is right: the `MaxAge` attribute expects a delta in seconds, not a timestamp; I doubt you want your cookie to persist in the browser for 40 years...

Comment: @jub0bs 4.11.2. I think this problem because nextjs doesn't allow set cookie from fetch on server (when I fetch in client component no errors and all good)